# Error with dateTime when I remove var_dump

Tags: php, date, datetime, var-dump

I get a date via json in the format dd/mm/yyyy but to save in the mysql database it needs to be in yyyy/mm/dd so I have to convert it:

```
var_dump($json);
```

> public 'data' => string '27/08/2018' (length=10)

When I run this code snippet:

```
if(isset($json->data) && $json->data !== '' && !is_null($json->data))
{
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $json->data);
    var_dump($dt);
    $parts = explode(' ', $dt->date);
    if(count($parts)>=1)
        $this->Objeto->data = $parts[0];

    var_dump($this->Objeto->data);
}
```

My `var_dump` is `'2018-08-27' (length=10)` and this is the expected result. But when I remove the `var_dump($dt)` it is returning the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in C:\wamp64\www\learning\controller\ControllerNotification.php

Why does this happen when I remove `var_dump`? How do I solve this problem?

Result when `var_dump($dt);` is run:

```
 object(DateTime)[8]
      public 'date' => string '2018-08-27 12:55:44.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'America/Sao_Paulo' (length=17)
```

Comment: That makes no sense as `var_dump()` is a stand-alone function.

Comment: [DateTime doesn't have a `date` property](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Why do you think it does?

Comment: when I run var_dump ($ dt) it shows me the date, I can not recover?

Comment: @JayBlanchard But it changes the object.

Comment: @JohnConde It does after `var_dump`

Comment: How so @AbraCadaver? It changes `$dt`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Yes https://3v4l.org/SIotH see the dupe, it is known.

Comment: Holy smokes @AbraCadaver! I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) it instead:

```
if(isset($json->data) && $json->data !== '' && !is_null($json->data)) {
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $json->data);
    $this->Objeto->data = $dt->format('Y/m/d h:i:s');
}
```